# Are Spore Galactic Adventures only about filming?

Tags: spore, spore-galactic-adventures

So far as I see. Spore: Galactic Adventures. Are only about filming and sharing stages with other players, judging by this video:

But their page: http://www.spore.com/what/ga says, it actually allows me to exit my spaceship and do mission both on planet as around the planets.

So what is it actually? Is it something that actually makes game richer or it expands the gameplay? Or it's just next tool, to generate videos which you are producer of?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A large part of Spore is about community-created content, but if you look for gameplay on YouTube you're only going to find videos people recorded to share with other players. So I wouldn't consider that meaningful.

Whether Galactic Adventures makes the game richer is really a matter of opinion. It adds some features, listed on their site, and more parts, etc. to customise your species -- so if you enjoyed the vanilla experience then you might find that it improves it.